# Android Local Host Refused to connect

Tags: android, apache, http, request

I am making an Http Connection to my server, it's apache server. Here is my code:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:8888/Main.php?request=2&token=N4565345");
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

But i'm not able to make this because, I get the next error:

> Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.0.1:8888 refused

I would be happy if someone can help me to fix that. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are on the same network with your server?

Comment: @Omolara Yes I they are  on the same network

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is loopback.  You're running a server on your phone?

Comment: @danbli1check my answer

Comment: @Omolara the server running on my computer, the phone on my local internet connection.

Comment: If you use 127.0.0.1 you can never get an error for 10.0.0.1. What are you doing that you are not telliing us?

Comment: @greenapps this is all but maybe it happened because this part of the code run in AsyncTask ?

Comment: Nonsense. But as said before: use the ip of your computer. What is the ip of your server computer? Did you find out already?

Answer (score 0):

The url you are calling should be referenced by the ip of your server. Like so:

```
URI website = new URI("http://yourIp/Main.php?request=2&token=N4565345");
```

Comment: But my Ip is my local ip, the server run on my computer and the app on the phone that connect to the same network as the computer.

Comment: It doesn't matter once both your computer and phone are on the same network. You can run ipconfig to get your IP.